# C++ Error using libxml2

Tags: c++, xml, libxml2

I am trying to parse and read xml files in c++ program using libxml2 library.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


static void 
print_element_names(xmlNode * a_node);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    xmlDoc         *doc = NULL;
    xmlNode        *root_element = NULL;
    xmlNodePtr      cur;
    xmlChar        *key;
    xmlAttrPtr     attr;
    const char     *Filename = "/home/praktyka/Dokumenty/road.xml";
    xmlChar        *d;

    doc = xmlReadFile(Filename, NULL, 0);

    if (doc == NULL)
    {
        printf("brak pliku %s\n", Filename);
    }

    else
    {
        root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
        print_element_names(root_element);
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
        xmlCleanupParser();
    }



   doc = xmlParseFile(Filename);

    if (doc == NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"parsed \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n-------------parsed!-------------\n\n");
    }

    xmlNodePtr svgnode = 0;

    cur = doc->xmlChildrenNode;
    while (cur != NULL) 
    {
     cout<<"--------- cur ptr = "<<(void*)cur<<"-----"<<endl;
     cout<<"--------- cur->name = "<<cur->name<<"-----"<<endl;
     cout<<"--------- cur->type = "<<cur->type<<"-----"<<endl;

        if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"svg"))) 
        {
    svgnode = cur; 

      }
      cur = cur->next;
    }

    if (!svgnode)
  {
   cerr<<"bad"<<endl;
 } 
    cur = svgnode->xmlChildrenNode;
    while (cur != NULL)  
    {
      if (!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"g")){
      break;
     }
     cur = cur->next;
    }    
     cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
    while ( cur != NULL )
    {
      if (!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"path")){
      break;
      }
      cur = cur->next;
    }     
     cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
    while ( cur != NULL )
    {
      if (!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"path:d")){
      break;
      }
      cout<<"--------------  cur->name = "<<cur->name<<"-----"<<endl;
      cur = cur->next;
    } 
     cout<<"--------- end----"<<endl;     
}
```

and I want to see value of `d` in compilator from this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg>
  <g>
    <path
       d="123"
       />
  </g>
</svg>
```

but my program doesn't work and does not create a make file. Why?

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? Does it crash? Does it even compile? You need to supply some additional information.

Comment: Please refer to http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: a program doesn't create a make file to start

Comment: warning: ‘void print_element_names(xmlNode*)’ used but never defined [enabled by default]

Comment: It is for you to write the Makefile, not the program!